# Creating a new Android emulator in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, emulation

I'm trying to create a new emulator through eclipse, but for some reason I can't choose a **Target** (ie, API 10)

I kinda messed up when installing my Android SDK and had to do it manually. Not sure if I'm supposed to place the SDK in a special location or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated all SDK Packages?
(Open Android SDK Manager, select the packages you want to install, then press Install and wait).

Comment: I sure have. I've already installed the versions I need. But I can't seem to create an emulator now.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the sdk manager (icon left to the device manager) that android 2.3.3 packages are well installed, if not install them